# Putting Freetypefont into libgdx skin

Tags: java, libgdx, freetype, scene2d

In my uiskin.json I have this

`com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: text/default.fnt } }`

This is fine for when I have the default.fnt in my text folder in the assets folder...

However I want to use a Freetypefont.

How do I create a Freetypefont and load it into the uiskin file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Update

Thanks to a comment from [Jos van Egmond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4537699/jos-van-egmond) telling me how to do this and still load the `Skin` from the `AssetManager` I have decided to update the answer. The old answer (and the alternative way of doing this) still remains untouched below.

The new procedure goes like this:

- Load your font files.
- Create an [`ObjectMap<String, Object>`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ObjectMap.html) and put your fonts in this map.
- Create a `SkinParameter` and give it the `ObjectMap` as a parameter.
- Load your `Skin` through the `AsserManager` as usual using the created `SkinParameter`.

The code might look something like this:

```
/* Load your fonts */
load font1...
load font2...

/* Create the ObjectMap and add the fonts to it */
ObjectMap<String, Object> fontMap = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
fontMap.put("font1", font1);
fontMap.put("font2", font2);

/* Create the SkinParameter and supply the ObjectMap to it */
SkinParameter parameter = new SkinParameter(fontMap);

/* Load the skin as usual */
assetManager.load("file/location/of/your/skin", Skin.class, parameter);
```

---

### Old

The current accepted answer is actually (kind of) incorrect. [This blog post](http://gigagrand.com/blog/?p=9) describes a way for you to reference generated `BitmapFont`s in your Json file. The procedure goes something like this:

- Create blank skin file using the default constructor.
- Add your fonts to the skin.
- Add your atlas file to your skin.
- Load your Json file to your skin.

The code might look something like this:

```
// Create a new skin using the default constructor and
// add your fonts to it.
Skin skin = new Skin();
skin.add("myFont", myFont, BitmapFont.class);

// Remember that this texture atlas is NOT automatically disposed by the skin, 
// so keep a reference and dispose of it yourself.
skin.addRegion(new TextureAtlas("file/location/of/your/atlas");
skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("file/location/of/your/skin"));
```

You can now do something like this in your skin Json:

```
...,
font: "myFont",
...
```

Although this is a workaround this also means that you cannot (at least I haven't found a way to) load your skin through an `AssetManager`. You can still load the `TextureAtlas` through the manager though.

Comment: To load a Skin with custom font via AssetManager, you can make use of the resource map argument in the SkinParameter class and pass the BitmapFont in there.

Comment: @JosvanEgmond Thank you, I did not think of this. I updated the answer.

Comment: Updated accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to do it beforehand, since you are going to generate it at runtime.

My workaround would be to keep the default font as it is and replace it at runtime via code. You can use [`Skin.add(...)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Skin.html#add-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) for that.

```
BitmapFont newDefaultFont = FreeTypeFontGenerator...;
skin.add("default-font", newDefaultFont, BitmapFont.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response...the text actually isn't blank but it has the "old" font instead of the newly added one.

Comment: Got it...If I can add to this it worked once I deleted the "default-font" that already existed in the json file. [link]http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8485&p=38863&hilit=skin+font#p38863[link]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The current answers didn't solve it, but helped clear it up. In my case, this worked:

```java
FreeTypeFontGenerator fontGenerator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("VT323.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter fontParameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

fontParameter.size = 24;
fontParameter.borderWidth = 3.6f;
fontParameter.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.3f);
fontParameter.borderColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.3f);

BitmapFont font = fontGenerator.generateFont(fontParameter);

fontParameter.size = 32;

BitmapFont title = fontGenerator.generateFont(fontParameter);

Skin skin = new Skin(new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("skins.atlas")));
skin.add("font", font);
skin.add("title", title);
skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("skins.json"));
```

The `skins.json`, `skins.atlas` and `skins.png` files were generated using the [Skin Composer](https://github.com/raeleus/skin-composer)